# re.findall('(ab|cd)', string) vs re.findall('(ab|cd)+', string)

Tags: python, regex

In a Python regular expression, I encounter this singular problem.
Could you give instruction on the differences between `re.findall('(ab|cd)', string)` and `re.findall('(ab|cd)+', string)`?

```py
import re

string = 'abcdla'
result = re.findall('(ab|cd)', string)
result2 = re.findall('(ab|cd)+', string)
print(result)
print(result2)
```

Actual Output is:

```
['ab', 'cd']
['cd']
```

I'm confused as to why does the second result doesn't contain `'ab'` as well?

Comment: re.findall('(ab|cd)', string)  gets ['ab', 'cd']
re.findall('(ab|cd)+', string) gets ['cd']

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if this will clear things more, but let's try to imagine what happen under the hood in a simple way,
we going to sumilate what happen using match

```py
   # group(0) return the matched string the captured groups are returned in groups or you can access them
   # using group(1), group(2).......  in your case there is only one group, one group will capture only 
   # one part so when you do this
   string = 'abcdla'
   print(re.match('(ab|cd)', string).group(0))  # only 'ab' is matched and the group will capture 'ab'
   print(re.match('(ab|cd)+', string).group(0)) # this will match 'abcd'  the group will capture only this part 'cd' the last iteration
```

`findall` match and consume the string at the same time let's imagine what happen with this REGEX `'(ab|cd)'`:

```
      'abcdabla' ---> 1:   match: 'ab' |  capture : ab  | left to process:  'cdabla'
      'cdabla'   ---> 2:   match: 'cd' |  capture : cd  | left to process:  'abla'
      'abla'     ---> 3:   match: 'ab' |  capture : ab  | left to process:  'la'
      'la'       ---> 4:   match: '' |  capture : None  | left to process:  ''

      --- final : result captured ['ab', 'cd', 'ab']
```

Now the same thing with  `'(ab|cd)+'`

```
      'abcdabla' ---> 1:   match: 'abcdab' |  capture : 'ab'  | left to process:  'la'
      'la'       ---> 2:   match: '' |  capture : None  | left to process:  ''
      ---> final result :   ['ab']
```

I hope this clears thing a little bit.

Answer (score 16):

`+` is a repeat quantifier that matches one or more times. In the regex `(ab|cd)+`, you are **repeating the capture group** `(ab|cd)` using +. This will only capture the last iteration.

You can reason about this behaviour as follows:

Say your string is `abcdla` and regex is `(ab|cd)+`. Regex engine will find a match for the group between positions 0 and 1 as `ab` and exits the capture group. Then it sees `+` quantifier and so tries to capture the group again and will capture `cd` between positions 2 and 3.

---

If you want to capture all iterations, you should **capture the repeating group** instead with `((ab|cd)+)` which matches `abcd` and `cd`. You can make the inner group non-capturing as we don't care about inner group matches with `((?:ab|cd)+)` which matches `abcd`

https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html

From the Docs,

> Let’s say you want to match a tag like `!abc!` or `!123!`. Only these two
>   are possible, and you want to capture the `abc` or `123` to figure out
>   which tag you got. That’s easy enough: `!(abc|123)!` will do the trick.
>
> Now let’s say that the tag can contain multiple sequences of `abc` and
>   `123`, like `!abc123!` or `!123abcabc!`. The quick and easy solution is
>   `!(abc|123)+!`. This regular expression will indeed match these tags.
>   However, it no longer meets our requirement to capture the tag’s label
>   into the capturing group. When this regex matches `!abc123!`, the
>   capturing group stores only `123`. When it matches `!123abcabc!`, it only
>   stores `abc`.

Comment: can you link to some doc making clear the fact that + only captures the last iteration, and what is a capture group?

Comment: @Gulzar, updated the answer. You can read about capture groups here - https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html

Comment: @Shashank, thanks, your reply is exactly what I need. sincerely thanks

Comment: There's no need to surround the whole regex with brackets. Just `'(?:ab|cd)+'` will work.

Answer (score 0):

So, for me confusing part was the fact that

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups;

[docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)

so it's returning you not a full match but only match of a capture. If you make this group not capturing `(re.findall('(?:ab|cd)+', string)`, it'll return `["abcd"]` as I initially expected